# Respect width of multi-column text div alongside siblings in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having trouble getting a text `div` to fit alongside a group of images in a `flexbox` row. These siblings currently only respect the `column-width` property of the text `div` as if it's a total width and overlap any width it has beyond this at various window sizes. The number of images and the length of the text is dynamic, as the content can change on page load. The layout is also responsive so I don't have the luxury of fixed dimensions in many cases. I believe I've reduced the problem to a working example with the following:

**HTML:**

```
<div id='maincontainer'>
  <div id='text'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quibus rebus efficiuntur voluptates, eae non sunt in potestate sapientis. In his igitur partibus duabus nihil erat, quod Zeno commutare gestiret. At cum de plurimis eadem dicit, tum certe
      de maximis. Pugnant Stoici cum Peripateticis. Qua tu etiam inprudens utebare non numquam. Duo Reges: constructio interrete.</p>

    <p>Beatus autem esse in maximarum rerum timore nemo potest. Quid est, quod ab ea absolvi et perfici debeat? Quarum ambarum rerum cum medicinam pollicetur, luxuriae licentiam pollicetur. Tubulum fuisse, qua illum, cuius is condemnatus est rogatione, P.
      Si id dicis, vicimus. Cur post Tarentum ad Archytam? Que Manilium, ab iisque M.</p>
  </div>
  <img class='img__gallery' src='https://placehold.it/200x300/a00/fff'>
  <img class='img__gallery' src='https://placehold.it/200x300/a00/fff'>
  <img class='img__gallery' src='https://placehold.it/200x300/a00/fff'>
  <img class='img__gallery' src='https://placehold.it/200x300/a00/fff'>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#maincontainer {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 300px;
    max-height: 550px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 800px; // not in original. Used to force the issue to show.
}
#text {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    column-width: 160px;
    height: 100%;
    column-gap: 20px;
    column-fill: auto;
}
.img__gallery {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

**Codepen:**
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ModaEN

As intended, the text appears before the images. It creates however many columns of 160px it needs to fit the text content in. However, the images don't start after the text content, but overlap the div (you can barely make out the majority of the text div peaking out behind the images in the CodePen example). There's a solution to this also through javascript but it feels OTT. Surely a multi-column text div can make room for itself inside a flexbox without other items crowding over it?

**In other words:**

Is there a way for the flex items inside `#maincontainer` to respect and make room for the total width of `#text` (while `#text` respects its own `column-width` property at all window sizes)?

Currently, either the other flex items (the images) overlap and don't respect the total width of `#text`, or else `#text` shrinks its columns to sizes much smaller than `column-width` at smaller window sizes. Given that I've stated a `column-width` (160px) for `#text`, the next flex item should begin at 480px + padding, etc. to the right of  the text if `#text` has 3 columns. 640px+padding if it has 4, etc.

If anybody is having trouble interpreting what I mean by *respect*, I'm inferring the action of making room for it. If an element's width ends at 200px, its next sibling should start at 200px+, etc. It's the behaviour most designers would be familiar with from relative positioning and/or floats. It's also the usual behaviour in flexboxes.

---

### Update

Querying the element width of `#text` in javascript (well, jquery, using `$("#textcontainer").width();`) returns a value identical to my specified `column-width` value.

Javascript (and therefore, I guess, the browser) is seeing the total width of the `#text` element as the `column-width` value, which would make some sense of why the neighbouring flex items are overlapping `#text` up to the width of one column. I've confirmed this in both Chrome and Safari on the latest releases of both on macOS.

I've actually made a working solution using javascript but would still be eager to avoid using it. It just seems a bit ridiculous that this basic composition need is as convoluted to solve as this.

### Update2

I'm not sure how this illustration better clarifies 'I need the sibling images to respect the total width of `#text` rather than overlapping it', but I'm including it incase it does, as requested. A is the required solution at all window sizes, B is what's happening:

[image]

Comment: I have difficulties to understand what you mean, so it would be great if you could provide a drawing/image/hardcoded sample of the wanted output.

Comment: Here's the same Codepen example without the width constraint, which I only used to force the problem: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgRNaO . Notice if you drag the window size that, at smaller size, the text goes under the images, rather than the images moving farther right to accommodate the widening text?

Comment: @biscuitstack: do you want the images to wrap after the text?

Comment: @karthick It wasn't a particular request in the original question, which ended more open-ended, but for my usage: no, `#maincontainer` expands to meet the width of its contained content and nothing wraps.

Comment: @bhv could you elaborate which part? I don't know how I could simplify 'siblings respect the width of a element' while describing that they're currently overlapping it. 'Respecting the width' to me means making room for it. If the width of an element is 200px, its neighbouring sibling would start at 200px+, etc.

Comment: AFAIK CSS columns and flexbox are basically incompatible with other. A flex container takes no notice of column declarations. I think (though I'm not sure, hence not an answer) that giving an element columns effectively takes it out of the flex flow, hence why it allows the text to overlap with the other elements in the container.

Comment: @ADyson This seems like an odd oversight for a straightforward layout requirement when using horizontal scrolling, no? In my research, it's not just `flexbox`, it's any positioning method that needs to dynamically respect the total width of a multi-column element.

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mfrf4fqL/)  this may works, change the layout using media queries for different devices ..

Comment: @biscuitstack I'd agree it's a bit unfortunate. I haven't read the specs for either to say in enough detail whether it's by design or not, it's just what I can observe. Sadly I think if you need the CSS columns in your div you might have go down the script route in order to correct it. I could be wrong but haven't seen a way round it as yet.

Comment: There is a [Flexbox bug with column-oriented flex containers](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#14-flex-containers-with-wrapping-the-container-is-not-sized-to-contain-its-items) that results in somewhat similar behavior (browser uses a single column width instead of full container width).

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn Well spotted. Looks like it's a defined bug. Which is a pity. Guess I'll need to stick to my javascript workaround for now. Since your highlighting of the bug description is the closest thing to a correct answer, I can give you the bounty if you enter it as an answer.

Comment: @ADyson , or anybody else who was answering. I'm obliged to hand out a bounty for this question and there's currently only a single answer that's incorrect. Since IlyaStreltsyn has gone MIA to my request, I'm happy to offer the bounty to anyone else who puts the figured out solution as an answer, with preference to ADyson for having the correct answer (without the citation given by IlyaStreltsyn).

Comment: @biscuitstack you mean you're happy for the answer to be "it won't work because there's a bug when using CSS columns", or you want a working solution?

Comment: @ADyson , it appears that there's no working solution that isn't a messy hack, and I had a solution of that sort from the beginning. The information that you and IlyaStreltsyn provided informed me with is as close to confirming this is the case as I've found and, therefore - when StackOverflow forces me to award a bounty after I've offered it - answers my issue.

Comment: @biscuitstack Can we use `margin` on `#text`.??  Adding `margin-right: 52%;` to  `#text` seems to be solving your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK CSS columns and flexbox are basically incompatible with each other. A flex container takes no notice of column declarations. It would appear that giving an element columns effectively takes it out of the flex flow, hence why it allows the text to overlap with the other elements in the container.

I haven't read the specs for either to say in enough detail whether this behaviour is by design or not, it's just what I can observe. Sadly I think if you need the CSS columns in your div you will have go down the script route in order to correct it. I could be wrong but haven't seen a way round it as yet.

As IlyaStreltsyn pointed out, there's a also a bug with column-oriented flex containers (https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#14-flex-containers-with-wrapping-the-container-is-not-sized-to-contain-its-items) which may be related to this as well.

Answer (score 1):

I created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/abinthaha/pen/prodQp) sample according to the illustration that you had. Hope this will help you with your problem.

We just need to give the parent the flex property and the flex-grow to the sibling images. I actually put the images in another container. So that it works like this. In case if you don't want to put the child's in another container, you can give `flex-grow: 1` to the images and `flex-grow: {numberof sibling images}` to obtain the half width of the `#mainContainer`

```
#maincontainer {
  display: flex;
}
#text, .image-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.image-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Very close, but I believe the bug is introduced when `#maincontainer` has a `position` value of *absolute*. It's unfortunately a value I need in my situation.

Comment: `position: absolute` is not a problem. Please add the container itself in another wrapper and give the parent `position: relative`. Also, the `#mainContainer` should have the full width. Make it sure by `width: 100%` or `left: 0; right: 0`

Comment: *And give the parent* `position: relative`. Is this under the assumption that this is of a benign outcome to its surrounding elements? The example I've included is just part of a bigger composition and `position: absolute` of `#maincontainer`, as I mentioned, is important to its layout. Including a new `relative` parent to enclose it isn't without consequences to the layout. There is a possibility of continuing down this avenue of multiple enclosing containers but javascript may be more elegant at this point. Though I do appreciate the advice offered.

Comment: Yes. I mean to say that `position: absolute` will eventually help a container to be positioned in any place we want it to be. But the problem is that the container will be positioned only within a wrapper whose `position` is `relative`.  Initially the `<body>` is what is `position: relative`. So if we want to position the container in a specific wrapper. We must specify the wrapper as `position: relative`

Answer (score -1):

I didn't get the whole problem:); Is this what you need? Check this codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ModaEN

```
<div id='maincontainer'>
    <p  class="flex-child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quibus rebus efficiuntur voluptates, eae non sunt in potestate sapientis. In his igitur partibus duabus nihil erat, quod Zeno commutare gestiret. At cum de plurimis eadem dicit, tum certe
      de maximis. Pugnant Stoici cum Peripateticis. Qua tu etiam inprudens utebare non numquam. Duo Reges: constructio interrete.</p>

    <p  class="flex-child">Beatus autem esse in maximarum rerum timore nemo potest. Quid est, quod ab ea absolvi et perfici debeat? Quarum ambarum rerum cum medicinam pollicetur, luxuriae licentiam pollicetur. Tubulum fuisse, qua illum, cuius is condemnatus est rogatione, P.
      Si id dicis, vicimus. Cur post Tarentum ad Archytam? Que Manilium, ab iisque M.</p>

  <img class='img__gallery flex-child' src='https://placehold.it/200x300/a00/fff'>
  <img class='img__gallery flex-child' src='https://placehold.it/200x300/a00/fff'>
  <img class='img__gallery flex-child' src='https://placehold.it/200x300/a00/fff'>
  <img class='img__gallery flex-child' src='https://placehold.it/200x300/a00/fff'>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#maincontainer {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 300px;
    max-height: 550px;
    height: 100%;
  width: 1400px;
}
.flex-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 200px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: "I didn't get the whole problem". Yep that's right unfortunately. You completely missed the bit where CSS columns are required to be used within the text container, which is the root of the problem.

Comment: it still doesn't contain any CSS columns in the sample above.